# SpaceWalk create Centos 8 Channel

Tags: centos, spacewalk

My Spacewalk is running on CentOS 7. We are managing the CentOS 7 server. Now I want to manage Centos 8 server also. When I create the channel it needs security GPG details. I am unsure what are GPG details for CentOS 8. How can I find this information for CentOS 8?

Here is CentOS 7 info:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the keys for CentOS 8. https://www.centos.org/keys/

You want the official key.

pub  4096R/8483C65D 2019-05-03 CentOS (CentOS Official Signing Key) 
        Key fingerprint = 99DB 70FA E1D7 CE22 7FB6  4882 05B5 55B3 8483 C65D

You can follow the format for what you already have above for CentOS 7:

```
GPG key URL: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Official

GPG key ID: 8483C65D

GPG key Fingerprint: 99DB 70FA E1D7 CE22 7FB6  4882 05B5 55B3 8483 C65D
```

Comment: The best way to retrive those keys through verified path is to install package distribution-gpg-keys.